# JS chain promises with result always resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise

I am still not 100% solid on how to chain promises.
Here is what I am trying to achieve:

I have one promise that resolves or rejects, The code further on picks up this and if the promise is resolved it goes on, if rejected it stops (not exactly, but good enough for this question). Now the problem is that I just want to run this promise, without caring if it resolves or rejects.

Way I had it before was simply:

```
function a(){
    return Service.doSomething();
}
```

So I wrapped it in other promise and the outcome is:

```
function a(){
    var q = $q.defer();
    Service.doSomething(); // I don't even need to handle whatever the outcome is
    q.resolve();
    return q.promise;
}
```

(Yes it is taken from angular project)

Now even thogh this works it just looks pretty ugly. Is there any better/nicer way I can write this?

**Update:**
I do realize that this looks like pretty strange behavior so I am going to explain a bit more.

This example is of angular routes and my custom middleware to handle authentication.

So I have created three "route" handlers:

- customRoute
- onlyGuest
- onlyUser

so instead of writing

```
$routeProvider.route({});
```

I write (for example)

```
$routeProvider.customRoute({});
```

Now each of those special route handlers extends *resolve* attribute of route with the authentication.

That way I can do this (for example):

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError',function(e, current, previous, rejection){
        // Only for logged in users
        if (rejection && rejection.needsAuthentication){
            $rootScope.refUrl = $location.path();
            $location.path('/user/login');
        }

        // Only for non-logged in users
        if (rejection && rejection.isOnlyGuest){
            $rootScope.refUrl = $location.path();
            $location.path('/dashboard');
        }
    });
```

Now the onlyGuest and onlyUser should be clear enough, but I also have customRoute() which basically runs the authentication method simply to retrieve user info if user accesses the app directly through this url and can be guest as well as can be logged in.

The problem is that when the authentication method throws reject() the route automatically fires changeError. So for this customRoute() I need to run the authentication but not go to changeError - always resolve as true even if authentication() promise rejects.

Not sure if its any clearer or just got more complicated...

Comment: I'm presuming `Service.doSomething()` is the first promise. If it is then you dont have it wrapped in another promise. You have another promise in a function with it. Also its unclear 1- what you are trying to do, 2 - what your question is.

Comment: @Tom... what you had before is correct. Why did you decide to change it? And if so, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @NewDev ok, im gonna update the question with more details - one minute

Comment: @Tom, then, indeed, you need to handle the error case, as the answer below suggests, except, I think it should be `.then(function(data){ return data;}, angular.noop)` - so that, in the event of success, the actual data is resolved.

Comment: @NewDev So you think in agular route I should return just value instead of promise?

Comment: @Tom, I'm not sure I follow... you return a promise, if your `doSomething` is a promise-returning async function. The `return data;` I referred to is the value that the promise ultimately delivers in success case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77632/discussion-between-tom-and-new-dev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So for this customRoute() I need to run the authentication but not go to changeError - always resolve as true even if authentication() promise rejects.

You seem to want to use [`catch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api) to ignore rejections:

```
function customRoute() {
    return authentication().catch(function(changeError) {
        // ignore error
        return true;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function a() {
    return Service.doSomething().then(angular.noop, angular.noop);
}
```

What happens? If you pass a function as the error callback to `then()` and that functions does *NOT* return `$q.reject(...)`, then the promise returned by `then()` is *resolved*, instead of being rejected.

See a little fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u6kzo1o0/

NOTE however that what you are trying to achieve seems strange, as per the comment of @New Dev.

Comment: I think it should be `.then(function(data){ return data;}, angular.noop)`

Comment: I wish I could accept two answers, both yours and accepted answer solved the issue, I just thought that using catch() is a little more elegant. If there is any downside to it please let me know!

Comment: @NewDev I tried and using noop for both works fine, as well as catch(angular.noop)

Comment: "Nikos Paraskevopoulos", Greece's Minister of Justice?

Comment: @Tom, both are fine. I would also prefer the `.catch`

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Hahahaha ha ha ha! (@everybody: sorry for the irrelevant comment, couldn't resist :)